# UICollectionView is nil after setting a variable

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

The collection view is nil when a variable did set. Everything works if I run in `viewDidLoad`. I've tried to fix and search all related posts but I can not get it through.

Here is my related code:

```
@IBOutlet var vnexpressContentCV: UICollectionView!
var link: String? {
        didSet {
             fetchData()
        }
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")
    vnexpressContentCV.register(UINib(nibName: "VNExpressContentCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: vnexpressContentCell)
    fetchData()
}
func fetchData() {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        if let text = link {
            Alamofire.request(text).responseRSS() { (response) -> Void in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    if let feed: RSSFeed = response.result.value {
                        self.items = feed.items

                        //this line below tells vnexpressContentCV is nil
                        self.vnexpressContentCV.reloadData() 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it exist in viewDidLoad (if you put a breakpoint), and before you make the network call?

Comment: Seems like you are setting Link , but your vnexpressContentCV is still nil at that time , and in didLoad you are registering cell nib then Data is shown there , You can try out one thing Take register nib and call to fetch data to a new func and call the new created func when you set the Link, i.e just take the didLoad Function Lines to a new func and give this a try

Comment: I've tried to put register nib to fetchData function but it stills tell me the error is vnexpressContentCV is nil

Answer (score 0):

It's nil because, while you set value of `var link: String` from source view controller by making instance of this viewcontroller, at that time `didSet` for `var link: String` will be called, but at that time this viewcontroller is not loaded UI components yet.

you can check if `vnexpressContentCV` is nil or not in `didSet` method in order to prevent app crash,

```
didSet {
    if let vnexpressContentCV = vnexpressContentCV {
        fetchData()
    }
}
```

Comment: but it wont be triggered again because the vnexpressContentCV always nil after the variable was set

Comment: in that case  you have to put fetchData() in viewWillAppear method.

Comment: viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad just only run one when we call the component. I want to trigger the collection view reloadData whenever I set the variable.

Comment: you can not reload data before even initialise collectionView. but you can go with delegation approach to accomplish your need.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that  `IBOutlet` is connected with the storyboard/xib.

```
 //this line below tells vnexpressContentCV is nil
 self.vnexpressContentCV.reloadData()
```

Please make sure that you are doing this after view is loaded in to memory.

Comment: it's already connected to the storyboard. It can run on viewDidLoad. Once the variable is set, it turns to nil

Comment: Actually your are fetching data before the collection view get initialise with storyboard outlet. Just try to put fetch call in view did load only for testing.

Comment: yeah. As I said, it runs well in the first initialise with storyboard. Once I set the variable, the vnexpressContentCV turns to nil